# Improve Performance Update query

Tags: sql-server

The script below columns are updated .
This update around 4 second.
are

```
while(@QCount<>0)
        begin
            select top 1 @QID=QuestionsId from #tempACResult
            --print @QID
            exec [CreditRisk].[Proc_CalcIndustryValue] @QID,@CaseRateDateId,@finalResult output

            update CreditRisk.AnswerResultcomplete set Result=Result + [Weight]*@finalResult,UnKnownResult=UnKnownResult  +[Weight]*@finalResult
             where CaseRateDateId = @CaseRateDateId and QuestionsId=@QID
            set @QCount=@QCount-1
            delete #tempACResult where QuestionsId=@QID
        end
```

Comment: Share the body of `[CreditRisk].[Proc_CalcIndustryValue]` in order to make it work with batches?

Comment: Also, if it is possible could upload the execution plan.https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: [CreditRisk].[Proc_CalcIndustryValue] is faster but query update is Slow

Comment: Have you tried measuring performance without updating each row one by one? The current code is doing updates RBAR (Row-by-agonizing-row). If your update set is relatively small then updating all #tempACResult at once would probably be fine, otherwise as gotgn suggested, batching would be more appropriate.